# Are there any good alternatives for jQuery popBox (a script that automatically extends a text field into a popup textarea in a dialog window?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dialog

I'm trying to find a replacement for popBox, a script that opens a textarea in a dialog window when you click a text input field in a form (more info at http://www.tpddesign.co.uk/blog/jquery-popbox/). Does anyone know of an existing alternative javascript/jquery script for this, or will I need to make one myself?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain why you need an alternative?

I know the download links were lost when the jQuery plugin site went down but it has just been hosted on GitHub - https://github.com/shibbard/jQuery-popBox/downloads

Comment: oh nice, that was why I needed an alternative. Thanks for this, I assumed the plugin was no longer being used and that the links wouldn't be replaced. I'll mark this as correct but if there are any others that anyone knows of it would be helpful to have alternative options!